# reset multiple select option value to zero

Tags: jquery, html

I asked a similar question before but with only one select option... this time i have multiple select options with the same id's... is it possible to reset all options to zero?

[**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5N7aR/)

my jquery (only works with first select):

```
$( "#reset" ).click(function() {
  $('#overtimehours').val(0);
});
```

### **html:**

```
<select class="overtimehours" id="overtimehours" name="overtimehours[165231]">
<option value="2.75">2.75</option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="0.25">0.25</option>
<option value="0.5">0.5</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="5.25">5.25</option>
</select>

<select class="overtimehours" id="overtimehours" name="overtimehours[165232]">
<option value="2.75">2.75</option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="0.25">0.25</option>
<option value="0.5">0.5</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="5.25">5.25</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="reset" value="reset"></input>
```

Comment: $('#overtimehours').val(0); needs to be $('.overtimehours').val(0); since it's a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the class as `id` attributes ***must*** be unique:

```
$( "#reset" ).click(function() {
  $('.overtimehours').val(0);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5N7aR/5/)

You will need to remove the duplicates otherwise your HTML will be rendered invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have same id on multiple elements. Replace it with the class.

Answer (score 1):

Change the

`$('#overtimehours').val(0);`

to

`$('.overtimehours').val(0);`

It's a class and not a ID.

Answer (score 1):

`id` must be unique, otherwise your selector will always match the first element with that duplicated `id`, so you need to assign different `id` value for each `select` element or remove all the duplicated `id`:

```
<select class="overtimehours" name="overtimehours[16523]">
    <option value="2.75">2.75</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="0.25">0.25</option>
    <option value="0.5">0.5</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="5.25">5.25</option>
</select>
<select class="overtimehours" name="overtimehours[165235]">
    <option value="2.75">2.75</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="0.25">0.25</option>
    <option value="0.5">0.5</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="5.25">5.25</option>
</select>
<select  class="overtimehours" name="overtimehours[165231]">
    <option value="2.75">2.75</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="0.25">0.25</option>
    <option value="0.5">0.5</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="5.25">5.25</option>
</select>
<select class="overtimehours" name="overtimehours[165232]">
    <option value="2.75">2.75</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="0.25">0.25</option>
    <option value="0.5">0.5</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="5.25">5.25</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="reset" value="reset"></input>
```

then you can use `.` to target your elements using class instead:

```
$("#reset").click(function () {
    $('.overtimehours').val(0);
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5N7aR/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Two things:
 1. IDs must be unique
 2. You can use class instead

See [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/5N7aR/4/)

```
<select class="overtimehours" id="overtimehours1" name="overtimehours[16523]">
<option value="2.75">2.75</option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="0.25">0.25</option>
<option value="0.5">0.5</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="5.25">5.25</option>
</select>

<select class="overtimehours" id="overtimehours2" name="overtimehours[165235]">
<option value="2.75">2.75</option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="0.25">0.25</option>
<option value="0.5">0.5</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="5.25">5.25</option>
</select>

<select class="overtimehours" id="overtimehours3" name="overtimehours[165231]">
<option value="2.75">2.75</option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="0.25">0.25</option>
<option value="0.5">0.5</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="5.25">5.25</option>
</select>

<select class="overtimehours" id="overtimehours4" name="overtimehours[165232]">
<option value="2.75">2.75</option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="0.25">0.25</option>
<option value="0.5">0.5</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="5.25">5.25</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="reset" value="reset"></input>


$( "#reset" ).click(function() {
  $('.overtimehours').val(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use class selector. id selector select first element in matched selector. also using duplicate id is bad practice. try this:

```
 $('.overtimehours').val(0);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5N7aR/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have used   `$('#overtimehours')` which will always return only one node. Avoid using multiple same IDs as IDs must be unique.

instead use

```
 $('.overtimehours').val(0);
```